# How to inject data in custom annotation from RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I create a custom annotation and HandlerInterceptorAdapter that will just get **memberNo** and print it out.

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation
{
    String memberNo();
}
```

And on Controller something like this:

```
@MyCustomAnnotation(memberNo = "${someBodyObject.memberNo}")
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test(@RequestBody SomeBodyObject someBodyObject) {
    System.out.println("--- TEST ---");
    return "-- FINISHED ---";
}
```

Request body SomeBodyObject have one filed and it's memberNo.

How can I inject that memberNo from RequestBody to HandlerInterceptorAdapter? 
And is it possible to user Spring SpEL or something else to get data from Body and send to AnnotationResolver?
Or maybe there is some other way to do this?

I try like this and response is: ${token.memberNo} as a String

Answer (score -1):

That's not possible.

Annotations require constant values and a method parameter is dynamic.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer but I don't think that is the case since you can use SpEL in huge range of annotation for example from spring documentation:

`@Cacheable(cacheNames="books", key="#isbn")

public Book findBook(ISBN isbn, boolean checkWarehouse, boolean includeUsed)`